# Visual studio 2022 project template issues c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, project-template

I'm trying to create a template of SFML-IMGUI

[image: Project Structure]

I can compile it and it works perfectly
(main function is inside main.cpp)

I've created **main.cpp** and **parametersUI.hpp** files, all others are from ImGui / SFML-ImGui

After creating the project template, it gives my this zip file :

[image: Template zip]

So all files seems to be here.
However, when I'm creating a project using this template :
**main.cpp** and **parametersUI.hpp** are missing. There're displayed on the project structure but files seems to be deleted, they're not physicaly in the project folder.

Futhermore, there are inside the xml file :

```xml
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="main.cpp">IMGUI\main.cpp</ProjectItem>
<ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="false" TargetFileName="parametersUI.hpp">IMGUI\parametersUI.hpp</ProjectItem>
```

Why visual studio doesn't want to include these 2 files ?

**EDITED PART**

I've tired to manualy remove IMGUI in the path (in xml file) and move these 2 files out of IMGUI in the zip but same missing file error when I'm creating a new project with this template

Comment: I'm not very familiar with project templates but should `IMGUI\main.cpp` be just `main.cpp`?

Comment: You should also check the project file itself, as the wizard engine will only copy files that are referenced by the project file (.vcxproj).